# How to group methods by region or some other grouping method for documentation?

Tags: c#, xml-documentation, sandcastle, docfx, maml

I have a large class that exposes many commands. When I create documentation for the class the methods are sorted alphabetically, but I would like to have them grouped by functionality. Is there a way (using Sand Castle Helpfile builder of DocFx) to accomplish this?

Comment: you should probably look in the documentation of those libraries. You can sort functions by many ways: `Attributes, List<string> {nameOf(Func1)}` stuff like that. if the libs dont provide a solution you might wanna use a different lib, or sort the generated HelpFiles afterwards with some parsing. Or just write your own HelpFile generator

Comment: You could declare an interface for each functionality group and add the doc comments to the interfaces. Of course the class would implement these interfaces.